# Torrentbox Hard Drive keeps unmounting when copying files. How to avoid it?

Tags: pi-3, power-supply, hard-drive, usb-power, alternative-power

My external hard drive is connected to a powered usb hub (5v 3000mA) then connected to rpi3. Whenever I copy any file that would take more than 30 sec, it would unmount and I have to mount the next letter (/dev/sd[letter]1).

Any suggestions on how to fix this? Would attaching another adapter to the hub, via usb, increase its output?

Comment: I would definitely recommend verifying power, including the quality of the cables used to connect devices. A robust power supply fed to your devices over a poor cable will cause failures. Check for errors in your logs that might give some indication of the cause.

Answer (score 1):

Sounds a lot like a power state issues.  Verify powers to the HDD.
It may be a good time to evaluate all power connections